# Allow allow AD Group access

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET website and I would like to only allow users in an AD group access to the site. I am using a web.config snippet as below, but this does not seem to work:

```
<authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
             <add accessType="Allow" roles="DOMAIN\GroupTest" />

        </authorization>
```

Any advice how to implement this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

You need to change your configuration as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="DOMAIN\GroupTest" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

As described in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(v=vs.100).aspx), ASP.NET looks for a matching `allow` or `deny` rule when granting access. If a matching `allow` rule is encountered first, access is granted.

Comment: Hmmm I get  an error stating the related configuration data is not valid:

    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="4" />
            <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="4" path="URL HERE" responseMode="Redirect" />
        </httpErrors>
        <security>
 
           <authorization>
    <allow roles="GLOBAL\DigitalSGTest" />
    <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>

Comment: The documentation shows that the `authorization` element needs to be placed unter `system.web` can you try this? See this part of the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: this works for me. I had to switch the allow to go first before the deny.